# ASP.NET Core - How to read EnvironmentVariableTarget after hosting in IIS

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have set `MyConnString` in System's environment variable in Windows 10 manually. I am trying to read it from code. In Visual Studio I can get the value of `MyConnString` using `EnvironmentVariableTarget.User`.

But after publishing and hosted in IIS, the value of `MyConnString` is returned as empty/null. My log is not printing the 'MyConnString' value.

My connection string is sensitive and can't be part of any config file. I appreciate your help.

I am using ASP.NET Core 3.1 and my app pool identity is `ApplicationPoolIdentity`. I have also set `Load User Profile` true in app pool.

```
var content = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MyConnString", EnvironmentVariableTarget.User);

if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(content))
{
    content = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MyConnString", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
}

if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(content))
{
    content = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MyConnString", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
}

if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(content))
{
    content = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MyConnString");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The *User* of IIS is not your user.

### FIRST OPTION

You need to set the variable for the user **owner of the process** of your IIS.

### SECOND OPTION

Use Environment variables inside your web.<environment>.config in order to be compatible in every server you deploy.

web.Staging.config

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <location>
        <system.webServer>
            <aspNetCore>
                <environmentVariables xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
                    <environmentVariable name="MyConnString"
                                         value="my db conn string"
                                         xdt:Locator="Match(name)"
                                         xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" />
                </environmentVariables>
            </aspNetCore>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

you have other possibilities to set the environment variables for your target server, search on G for more infos.

Comment: My connection string is sensitive and can't be part of Web.Config

Comment: Good, find under which user runs your IIS and set the variable in that user environment,